# How to read TextBox objects with NPOI?

Tags: c#, npoi

I have a XLSX Workbook with one single sheet with 5 TextBox (A1 to A5).

How to get/set this objects values?

Tnks

Answer (score 0):

Textbox is not supported to be read in NPOI.